# regex for phone, but want to make if all 10 digits are the same to be invalid

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

I'm trying to validate a phone field using data-ng-pattern. It validates that its all numbers if there are 10 digits.

```html
<input type="text" name="phone_number" placeholder="Phone" tabindex="7" data-phone-mask="(***) ***-****" data-ng-pattern="/^\([0-9]{3}\) [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/" data-error-msg="Please enter your ten digit phone number" required data-ga-event="FormField_Phone" data-event-type="fieldsubmit" data-category="FormField">
```

However, i want the input to be invalid when all 10 digits are the same.

Invalid example: (444) 444-4444, (515) 515-155
Valid example: (444) 424-4444

Comment: There are more things that make a phone number invalid than "all the same digit".

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol essentially i want to use my current regex but addition to that the make all same 10 digits invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You can prepend patterns of the form:

```
(?!this isn't valid)
```

Put that just after the `^` at the start, before anything else. If that is found, then it fails. An example for your case might be:

```
(?!\((\d)\1\1\) \1{3}-\1{4})
```

This should reject the input if it consists of all the same digit.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?!\((.)\1\1\)\s*\1\1\1-\1\1\1\1)\([0-9]{3}\) [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$
```

Try this.See demo.Just add a lookahead to check if all digits are not same.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/65

Answer (score 0):

you can use a look ahead for this issue

```
/^\(([0-9])(?!\1{2}\) \1{3}-\1{4})[0-9]{2}\) [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/
```

Basically you are capturing the first digit then checking all following digits to see if they match or not, `([0-9])` grabs the first digit, `(?!\1{2}\) \1{3}-\1{4})[0-9]{2}\)` is a negative lookahead

Basically a way to check everything in the string without progressing forward in your main pattern

Checks to see if the remaining digits are the same then don't match